# Random Tic-Tac-Toe image flipping

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, imageicon

I have created a basic Tic-Tac-Toe class which displays 9 buttons showing random images on it(each run time - different sequences). The main method is there in another test class, which is just a frame creator. In addition to this, I want to add some event handling. I have added 'ActionListener' to the buttons & want to add some logic in 'actionPerformed' method. Each time I click on any button it should change an image continuously in order X -> O -> Blank -> X. I am not sure that which logic will fit here to flip images in above order(for e.g. for-loop,switch etc.). The code is as follows :

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

  public JButton[][] labels = new JButton[3][3];
  public ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[3];
  public int r, c;

  public TicTacToe() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));


    for (r = 0; r < labels.length; r++) {
     for (c = 0; c < labels.length; c++) {
      int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 0);
      System.out.println(random);
      JButton s = new JButton(this.icons[random]);
      this.add(s);
      this.labels[r][c] = s;

      if (random == 0) {
       System.out.println("Cross Image Icon");
       labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\cross_symbol.gif"));
       add(labels[r][c]);
       validate();
      } else if (random == 1) {
       System.out.println("Not Image Icon");
       labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\zero_symbol.gif"));
       add(labels[r][c]);
       validate();
      } else if (random == 2) {
       System.out.println("Keep it blank");
       labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
       add(labels[r][c]);
       validate();
      }

      labels[r][c].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

     }
    }


   } // end of TicTacToe constructor 

  public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    } // end of actionPerformed method 

  } // end of ButtonListener class                  


 } // end of TicTacToe class

 import javax.swing.*;

 public class TicTacToeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToe frame = new TicTacToe();
    frame.setTitle("Let's play a random tic-tac-toe game !!!!!");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

   } //end of main method       
 } // end of test class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method setText to put an X or O on the JButton like so.
All you need to add if a variable that will know if it's X or O turn.
Hopefully this help

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
     {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            Object src = e.getSource();
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if(src==labels[i][j]&&labels[i][j].getText()==""){
                        //if X turn 
                        labels[i][j].setText("X");

                    }
                    //if O turn
                    //labels[i][j].setText("O");
                }
            }

                }// end of actionPerformed method 

     } // end of ButtonListener class
```

Comment: Yikes. ***NEVER*** do `if (someString == "")`. Never use `==` to compare Strings. Use the equals method instead or here you could do, `if (xxx.isEmpty())`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , do you mean in the if statement above in answer? [if(src==labels[i][j]&&labels[i][j].getText()=="")]

Comment: @user3466619: yes. You should never compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: @user3597579 , actually I do not want to add any text on button, since I do have the existing images. So I am trying with getIcon method, but unable to use it. So is it possible to do like,  '//ImageIcon n= new ImageIcon("");  ImageIcon x= new ImageIcon("\x.gif");  ImageIcon o= new ImageIcon("\o.gif");                 [if(src==labels[i][j]&&labels[i][j].equals(n))]' OR '[if(src==labels[i][j]&&labels[i][j].getIcon()==null)]' and then 'labels[i][j].setIcon(x);' OR ''labels[i][j].setIcon(o); ''

Comment: Yes this is possible, I recommend using another Label array. You put icon[0] as nothing, icon[1]= X and icon[2]=O. You use if(labels[i][j].getIcon()==icon[0]) //empty. if(labels[i][j].getIcon()==icon[1]) //This is an X. if(labels[i][j].getIcon()==icon[2]) //This is an O

Answer (score 1):

So I added 'switch' inside 'for' loops, so that each time I click a button it flips an image in particular order. I wanted the same images to flip not any text, so I used 'setIcon()' method. For that I created three ImageIcon objects in main class.A counter is added for three different cases & it keeps looping.

My final answer code is as follows :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
    {
        public JButton[][] labels = new JButton[3][3];
        public ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[3];

        byte value=0;
        public ImageIcon x= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\cross_symbol.gif");
        public ImageIcon o= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\zero_symbol.gif");
        public ImageIcon n= new ImageIcon("");      

        public TicTacToe() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


            for(int r=0; r<labels.length ; r++)
            {
                for(int c=0; c<labels.length ; c++)
                {
                    int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 0);
                    System.out.println(random);
                    JButton s = new JButton(this.icons[random]);
                    this.add(s);
                    this.labels[r][c] = s;

                        if(random == 0)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Cross Image Icon");
                        labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\cross_symbol.gif"));
                        add(labels[r][c]);
                        validate();
                        }    
                        else if(random == 1)
                        {
                                System.out.println("Not Image Icon");
                                labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\workspace\\hw3pandarey\\src\\hw3pandarey\\zero_symbol.gif"));
                                add(labels[r][c]);
                                validate();
                        }
                        else if(random == 2)
                        {
                                System.out.println("Keep it blank");
                                labels[r][c].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
                                add(labels[r][c]);
                                validate();
                        }

                       labels[r][c].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

                    }
                }
        } // end of TicTacToe constructor 

         public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
         {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {

                    if(e.getSource()==labels[r][c])
                    {
                        value++;
                        value%=3;
                        switch(value)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            labels[r][c].setIcon(n);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            labels[r][c].setIcon(x);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            labels[r][c].setIcon(o);
                            break;              
                        } // end of switch

                    }// end of 'if' 

                } // end of inside for loop   

                }  // end of outside for loop           

            } // end of actionPerformed method

         } // end of ButtonListener class

    } // end of TicTacToe class
```